# Does entrust 5.2 package supports with laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5

Can I install entrust 5.2 with laravel version 5.4 to assign roles and permissions to the users???? I installed and tried. But I can not able to assign roles. I am getting error status 403. Can Anyone help?

Comment: Please provide more information. Your question is very vague and could involve a number of different causes.

Answer (score 0):

An error 403 is an unauthorized action response, which in all likeliness has nothing to do with Entrust, and more so to do with your routes and current authorization rules. Can you verify you have access to the routes you are trying to send requests to? It does not need to involve the Entrust package, simply making GET or POST requests through a basic form will do.